# Access VBA/SQL Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I receive the following error when trying to run a line of SQL in an Access database: `Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.`

VBA stops at this line of code:

```
Set rst = appAcc.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(LW_Data, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Here is where I define LW_Data:

```
LW_Data = "SELECT [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller, [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[Caller Name], [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[Caller Level] AS [Lvl], [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[Final Dispos] AS [FDs], [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[$/Final Dispo] AS [PFD], [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[Average Gift] AS [Average], [TbC LW: Check $].[Check Count] AS [Ck], [TbC LW: Check $].[Check $] AS [Ck $], [TbC LW: Check $].[Check $ Paid] AS [Ck Paid], [TbC LW: Credit Card $].[CC Count] AS [CC], " & _
"[TbC LW: Credit Card $].[CC $], [TbC LW: Credit Card $].[CC $ Paid], [TbC LW: SIs].[Send Infos] AS SIs, [TbC LW: DNCs].CountOfDisposition AS [DNCs], [TbC LW: Check $].[Ck Paid], [TbC LW: Credit Card $].[CC Paid], [TbC LW: Q4].Q4, [TbC LW: Hour Figures].[$/HR], [TbC LW: Hour Figures].[FD/HR], FormatPercent(Round((Nz([TbC LW: Check $]![Check Count],0)+Nz([TbC LW: Credit Card $]![CC Count],0))/[TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR]![Final Dispos],2),0) AS [Pldg/FD], " & _
"[TbC LW: Hour Figures].SumOfPledge, [TbC LW: Hour Figures].SumOfHours,[TbC LW: Check $]![check count]+[TbC LW: Credit Card $]![cc count] AS [Pldge Count], Left([CurrentProject].[Name],Len([CurrentProject].[Name])-6) AS [Camp] " & _
"FROM ((((([TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR] LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: Check $] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: Check $].Caller) LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: DNCs] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: DNCs].Caller) LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: Credit Card $] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: Credit Card $].Caller) LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: SIs] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: SIs].Caller) LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: Q4] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: Q4].Caller) LEFT JOIN [TbC LW: Hour Figures] ON [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller = [TbC LW: Hour Figures].Caller " & _
"ORDER BY [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].[Caller Level], [TbC LW: Final Dispos / HR].Caller;"
```

Here is where I get completely lost. I define other variables as SQL statements and they run fine in this same line of code, so I'm correctly connected to the database and the syntax in the line is correct. I'm convinced that there is a formatting error within the variable definition of LW_Data. But if I manually open the database, create a new query, and paste this code in, it runs just fine (Substituting out the lines breaks of course).

Can anyone shine light on this? I've checked to make sure all the tables and fields to exist as well, like I said, I can run this manually within the database just fine. But doing it from VBA in Excel seems impossible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+run-time+error+3061 Also, please try to read what you posted here, and then [edit] to at least make an effort to format it. If you're not sure how, click the little **?** button above the top-right corner of the textarea for markup help. While you're editing, you can also improve your title so it explains the problem you're having or question you're asking. All you've done here is repeat the information available in the tags and added *SQL error*, which is useless. Your title should be clear enough to be of use to future readers in search results.

Answer (score 1):

I found this piece of code in your SQL query containing VBA:

`Left([CurrentProject].[Name],Len([CurrentProject].[Name])-6)`

It should look something like this

```
 Left( "&[CurrentProject].[Name]&",Len("&[CurrentProject].[Name]&")-6)
```